# Could not find unicorn (>= 0) amongst

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, unicorn

I'm currently using capistrano to deploy my project. However I'm having this problem below:

```
$ cap deploy:start

* executing `deploy:start'
  * executing " /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/unicorn_rails -c /app/current/config/unicorn.rb -E production -D"
    servers: ["x.x.x.x"]
    [x.x.x.x] executing command
 ** [out :: x.x.x.x] /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.**rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find unicorn (>= 0) amongst [minitest-1.6.0, rake-0.8.7, rdoc-2.5.8]** (
 ** [out :: x.x.x.x] Gem::LoadError)
 ** [out :: x.x.x.x] from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
 ** [out :: x.x.x.x] from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1210:in `gem'
 ** [out :: x.x.x.x] from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/unicorn_rails:18:in `<main>'
 ** [out :: x.x.x.x] 
    command finished in 253ms
failed: "sh -c '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/unicorn_rails -c /app/current/config/unicorn.rb -E production -D'" on x.x.x.x
```

software version:

- rails 3.1
- ruby-1.9.2-p290
- ubuntu 10.04

Could anyone help? Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capistrano can't find the right variable of PATH,GEM_PATH and GEM_HOME.You should set them in `config/deploy.rb` like below:

```
set :default_environment, {
  'PATH' => "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:$PATH",
  'RUBY_VERSION' => 'ruby 1.9.2p290',
  'GEM_HOME' => '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290',
  'GEM_PATH' => '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `Unicorn` gem is not installed on the server.

Login into the server and run

```
which unicorn_rails
```

If it doesn't return any path, it means it's not available. Login as root, then install it.

```
$ gem install unicorn
```

Comment: Thanks Simone. 
Yes it does return the path as 
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/unicorn_rails

Comment: Try to execute the command `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/unicorn_rails -c /app/current/config/unicorn.rb -E production -D` directly on the server and see if it works

Comment: yeap. It works. Just does NOT work by calling through capistrano. :(